# type of property txtname (uiTextView *) does not match of ivar txtname(uiTextView)

Tags: iphone, uitextview

```
    //  ViewController.h
    @interface ViewController : UIViewController{

        IBOutlet UIButton *btnname;
        IBOutlet UITextView *txtname;
        IBOutlet UILabel *lblname;

    }


    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtname;

    @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblname;

    - (IBAction)Btntikla:(id)sender;

    @end

    //ViewController.m

    @implementation ViewController

    @synthesize txtname;//here it says -type of property txtname (uiTextView *) does not match of ivar txtname(uiTextView)- this mistakes

    @synthesize lblname;

- (void)dealloc {
    [lblname release];
    [txtname release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (IBAction)Btntikla:(id)sender {

    NSString *name=[txtname text];
    lblname.text=name;
}
@end
```

//my whole program is this.it gives this error?type of property txtname (uiTextView *) does not match of ivar txtname(uiTextView)..Can you help me pls?? what is my mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's beacause you have

```
 @property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtname;
```

and

```
IBOutlet UITextView *txtname;
```

And `UITextField` and `UITextView` are differents controls

Comment: yeah thank u so much .ı have just realized.but ı have another problem ..ı cant see my button ,textbox on the simulator??

Comment: have you connected the outlets in InterfaceBuilder?Are you using .xib file at all? You have to be more specific to make the community able to help you.